# Android Store data from ByteBuffer to Storage

Tags: android, streaming, bytebuffer, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm broadcasting the stream using a third party sdk and after adding callback I'm successfully able to get the `ByteBuffer` of audio but when I saved it to the sdcard not able to play it.

here is snippet of my code

```
    long startedTime = -1;

    @Override
    public void onAudioBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, int i, long l) {
        if (bufferedOutputStream == null)
            createFile();
        Log.e(TAG, "i:" + i);
        Log.e(TAG, "l:" + l);
        Log.e(TAG, "byteBuffer capacity:" + byteBuffer.capacity());
        Log.e(TAG, "byteBuffer length:" + byteBuffer.array().length);
        if (startedTime == -1) {
            startedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            createFile();
        } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startedTime > 10000) {
            try {
                bufferedOutputStream.close();
                startedTime = -1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "byteBuffer bufferedOutputStream closing err:" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        } else {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.capacity()];
                byteBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes);
                byteBuffer.clear();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "byteBuffer bufferedOutputStream writhing err:" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:-

```
try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            byteBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "byteBuffer bufferedOutputStream writhing err:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

finally close the byteBuffer after operation or copping all.

Comment: Same issue unable to play the file

Comment: There is no error while writing the file , the only thing is that I can not play the mp3 file

Comment: how you are creating file? look for extensions and all